# Load a properties file in a jar file

Tags: java

I was trying to work on a java program with requires a properties file attached to the jar. Thus, i did jar the program, and unjar it to attach a properties file. I have a class, MyClass, which requires the properties file. Thus, i basically put the properties file to the same folder as MyClass.class. Then I jarred it back.

In my MyClass.java, i was trying to access the properties by:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("prop.properties"));
```

Where prop.properties is in the same folder as my MyClass.class.

It failed to load it. Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: did you try `prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/prop.properties"));`?

Comment: Try MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream instead.

Comment: I also tried prop.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/prop.properties")); but it didn't work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` treats the path as relative to the root of the classpath, i.e. it looks for resources at the root level of each JAR or directory on the class loader.

You probably want `Class.getResourceAsStream`, which treats the path as being relative to the package of the class in question.  You also need to make sure to close the stream once you've read it.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("prop.properties");
try {
  prop.load(in);
} finally {
  in.close();
}
```

If `MyClass` is in the package `com.example` then this will load `com/example/prop.properties` from the JAR.